# How can I convert a generic datatype in C#?

Tags: c#-4.0

See the method below [Not Working as expected].I want double or int as method parameters and return as any data type [in my case return as int,double or string].

Requirement:
if the double or int value is zero then return an empty string else the real int or double value. **I don't want to use dynamic as return type**

```
private static T CheckZero<T>( dynamic val ) {
        return Math.Sign(val) == 0 ? (T)Convert.ChangeType(string.Empty, typeof(string)) : val;
    }
```

Comment: It's very unclear what you're asking for, to be honest. If the method might return a string but might return an `int` or `double`, then you really need to declare that it will return `object` or some interface that all of those types supported.

Comment: @Jon I want to accept double values [12.32] .if it's zero then return an empty string else 12.32

Comment: @Krish - show us the calling code - what does it look like. E.g. `int a = CheckZero<int>(b);` obviously isn't going to work because your method might return a string - so how do *you* imagine the calling code will be structured? Or better yet, give us more of a picture of what *problem* you're trying to solve, such that the code you're trying to write is part of the *solution*.

Comment: @all i have sorted the issue with object as the return type.Thanks guys